# Efficiently calculating half of the eigenvectors of a sparse array

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

### Eigenvectors of a sparse array

###### $\quad$ Problem statement

I want to calculate the eigenvectors corresponding to the negative eigenvalues of an $8L^2 \times 8 L^2$ matrix ($L \sim 30 )$. Most of the elements of this matrix are zero, so I am using a [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html). The eigenvalues of the matrix ranges in $[-6,6]$, and occurs in pairs, so I am interested in the half of the eigenvectors.

###### $\quad$ Brute force solution

In the last section I show the particular matrix of my problem, but I understand that my problem happens for any Hermitian sparse array. So consider the simple example

```
sa[n_] := 3/ Cos[π/(n + 1)]
SparseArray[ {Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1 }, {n,n}];
```

I have scaled the matrix so that the eigenvalues runs in $[-6,6]$, and here $n=8L^2 \sim 7200$. Using the standard [`Eigensystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) and asking for the eigenvectors corresponding to negative eigenvalues I've write

```
ev[matrix_] :=  Module[n = Length[matrix], 
  Transpose[Sort[Transpose@Eigensystem@N@matrix][[1 ;; n/2]] ][[2]]  ]
```

Using this code for $L=20$ $(n=3200)$ it tooked about 2 second and a warning saying that the matrix will be converted to a normal one:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ev@sa[3200];]
    Eigensystem::arh: Because finding 3200 out of the 3200 eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors is likely to be faster with dense matrix methods, the sparse input matrix will be converted. If fewer eigenvalues and/or eigenvectors would be sufficient, consider restricting this number using the second argument to Eigensystem.
(* {2.37376, Null} *)
```

For this value $L=20$ the time is acceptable, but for $L=30$ the time is about $30$ seconds. I also need to remark that my real matrix has more elements than `sa`, and for the case where $L=20$ find the eigensystem already takes about $40$ seconds. In my real code I need to call this function about fifty times, so I can't really work with matrices as large as I need using this method.

###### $\quad$ Tentative solution

Since I don't need all eigenvectors, I try to use the `Method->"FEAST"` choosing interval `{-6,0}`. Without specifying the `"SubspaceSize"` the code don't run `Eigensystem::Warning: Subspace dimension is too small for the FEAST method. Increase the option "SubspaceSize".`. However, there are not much specification in the methods for FEAST [see Options>Method>"FEAST"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html), the documentation only says

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| "ContourPoints" | select the number of contour points |
| "Interval" | an interval for finding eigenvalues |
| "MaxIterations" | the maximum number of refinement loops |
| "NumberOfRestarts" | the maximum number of restarts |
| "SubspaceSize" | the initial size of subspace |
| "Tolerance" | the tolerance to terminate refinement |
| "UseBandedSolver" | whether to use a banded solver |

For me it is not clear the best choice for those parameters, and the documentation lack examples. I tried some values of `"SubspaceSize"` and none of them give a good time. I used the function

```
ev2[matrix_,ss_] := 
 Module[{n = Length[matrix]},   Transpose[Sort[Transpose@
       Eigensystem[N@matrix,Method -> {"FEAST", "Interval" -> {-6.1, 10^-10}}, "SubspaceSize" -> ss] ][[1 ;; n/2]] ][[2]]  ]
```

which give times much worst than the initial function `ev`

```
AbsoluteTiming[ev2[sa[3200], 1000];]
(*{14.1154, Null}*)
```

##### Question: what is the most efficient method to calculate the eigenvectors corresponding to half of the set of eigenvalues?

##### Edit: The particular type of matrix

The matrix that I am interested can be written as a $L^2 \times L^2$ matrix with blocks of size $8\times8$. For $L=3$ matrix is
[image: matrix]
where $\text{h.c.}$ means that I am adding the Hermitian conjugate of the same matrix, and each $Hx, Hy$, and $Hz$ are $8\times 8$ matrices. The expression for each of these blocks is complicated and are different for each block.  Without getting too much into the details, my problem is self-consistent, meaning that I write the matrix as a function of some set of parameters. I start with a guess for the parameters, then I use the eigenvectors for the matrix to recalculate the set of parameters, with the matrix applied to the new set of parameters I repeat the process until the set of parameters converges. Therefore, I can't write the numerical value for the matrix.

Comment: If the matrix is only of size $30 \times 30$ then you are definitely best of with dense matrix methods. IIRC, LAPACK has also specific routines for banded matrices such as yours. But I don't know of a built-in way to call these routines from within _Mathematica_. One would have to write a LibraryLink interface.

Comment: Ironically, your matrix is already tridiagonal; and the first and most costly step in LAPACK is to reduce a general matrix to tridiagonal form. And then it uses very efficient routines for such matrices. So you could in principle skip the preparatory step and call those routines...

Comment: Hey @HenrikSchumacher, this matrix is just an example. The matrix that I am interested is not tridiagonal neither banded, but it is sparse. Also, the dimensions of the matrix is $n \times n$ where $n=8L^2$, so the matrix size is more like $7200 \times 7200$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Which such things the particular structure of the matrix is important. Can you post it?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I add an image of matrix in the post.

Comment: Hm. So your actual goal is not to compute the eigensystem, but to solve some nonlinear equation for the matrix' parameters? If that's the case, then computing the eigensystem in the first place is a very bad idea. What about just employing Newton's method? That only requires solving linear equations involving sparse matrices; and that can be done very efficiently.

Comment: You could use the `Arnoldi` method with a criterion on the real part: `Eigensystem[matrix, Length[matrix]/2, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, the dependence of the matrix in the parameters is linear. I said that it is complicated because there are $64 L^4$ parameters. Nonetheless, I just want to find the eigenvectors. I don't know how to use Newton's method in this case because the parameter is a expression evolving the eigenvectors of the matrix (and it is not possible to use symbolic calculation to find the eigenvector for such large matrices).

Comment: Hey @Roman, I used your idea with `-matrix` to find corresponding to the negative energies. For small matrix it worked. But for $n=3200$ it does not converged. Took about 30 seconds to and said `Eigensystem::maxit2: Warning: maximum number of iterations, 3200, has been reached by the Arnoldi algorithm without convergence to the specified tolerance, but the current best computed value has been returned. You can use method options with Method -> {Arnoldi, opts} to increase the size of basis vectors, the maximum number of iterations, reduce the tolerance, or use an estimate as a shift ...` .

Comment: Use `Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart", MaxIterations -> 10^6}`